# Randomizing pairing in "gift swawp"

Tags: algorithms, sorting

## The problem

I'm arranging a "gift swap" for Christmas with N people involved (N > 2).

I want to create an algorithm that generate the pairing gifter->giftee so that:

1. everyone receives a gift
2. no one sends gift to themselves
3. no pair end in a "gift-closed loop" (person 1 sends gift to person 2, person 2 sends gift to person 1)

**Is there an algorithm that satisfies these 3 requirements?**

## My approach (so far)

For the following tests/examples, I use N = 4. So the involved people are 0, 1, 2 and 3.

### Easy approach

An easy way to satisfy all the 3 requests is to create a list of the involved people, where person[i] sends the gift to person[i + 1] (at the end of the list, person[N - 1] sends gift to person[0]). In our 4 people example, we have the list:

```
0 1 2 3
```

and we have that

```
0 sends gift to 1
1 sends gift to 2
2 sends gift to 3
3 sends gift to 0
```

Easy and functional. Win-win. But...

### Need more randomness

Participants will subscribe to the event. There will be the first subscriber, then the second, ... Given the nature of the group that will participate, it is quite likely that the first X participants will subscribe to the event in the same chronological order in the next years. So, next year, I'll have the same gifter->giftee pairs for them. I don't like it.

To overcome the problem, I've added a preliminary "list scrambling" step. So, from the original list

```
0 1 2 3
```

I generate a scambled version of the list

```
1 3 2 0
```

so now we have that

```
1 sends gift to 3
3 sends gift to 2
2 sends gift to 0
0 sends gift to 1
```

Note: it can happen that I get the exact same scrambled list next year, so I still have the "same pairing" problem. But it's quite unlikely. Or better, unlikely enough for me.

Due to the "person[i] sends the gift to person[i + 1]" algorithm, this still satisfies requests (1) and (2). But...

### The "gift-closed loop" problem

It can happen that the randomized list will be

```
1 0 3 2
```

so we have that

```
1 sends gift to 0
0 sends gift to 1
3 sends gift to 2
2 sends gift to 3
```

So we have a "gift-closed loop" between 0 and 1, and between 2 and 3.

NOTE: there are a couple more examples that produce this problem

My main questions are: **How do I prevent this problem? Is there a randomizing algorithm that avoid this?**

### Iterative method

There is an iterative method to avoid this, that is:

- check if a closed loop exists
- if it exists, do one of the following:

  - generate a new random list (brute force method)
  - take one of the people in the closed loop from the list and swap with another random person in the list
- loop until the problem is solved

This will work...eventually... I really don't like the iterative approach.

Comment: I would probably make a graph where each person is a node and each potential gift giving relationship is an edge (then you can also prevent repetition of last years relations by removing the edges corresponding to how gifts were given last year), and then use a standard algorithm for finding a Hamiltonian path in that.

Comment: Sounds interesting, although a little more complicated than what I planned. Preventing pairing repetitions is surely a plus, but you have to consider that the pool of people participating can change; I don't know if this can screw something (I have to study your proposal more deeply)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shuffle the numbers $0,1,2,\dots,n-1$ into a random order.  Then each person finds their place in this order and gives a gift to the next person in this order.  This meets all of your requirements, and introduces plenty of randomness.

For instance, the sequence $1,0,3,2$ means that 1 gives to 0, 0 gives to 3, 3 gives to 2, and 2 gives to 1.  There is no "gift-closed loop".

Comment: Well, so long as $n>2$ there’s no ordered 2-cycle (which is what the OP explicitly said was undesirable) but the whole thing **is** one big ordered $n$-cycle. OP was unclear about whether that’s a “closed loop.”

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum, to me it seems pretty clear that my answer meets the requirements.  I think the only viable interpretation of the question is that it prohibits 2-cycles but not other cycles.  1. The definition of "gift-closed loop" is written as a 2-cycle.  2. The first two examples given in the question, which are apparently acceptable, are both $n$-cycles.  3. *Every* solution involves a $k$-cycle for some $k$, so it's not possible to avoid all cycles.  I'm not sure how you're interpreting the question, but if you think it's ambiguous, leave a comment on the Q asking the author to clarify?

Comment: @D.W. You know what? That's exactly what I came to while ruminating on the problem this night. Meets the requirements and keeps the super-simple approach already proposed. Aready had the solution in my hand, but I was randomizing in the wrong step.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum I'm not sure what is uncler to you, since I don't really know what an "ordered 2-cycle" actualy is (will check later). But, as said, I confirm that the proposed solution meets my requirements